# Apps installed by snap duplicates in the panel in Linux Mint 21.2

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, snap

I have installed the Blender Snap package and I would like to pin it to my panel. I did so, but now when I open Blender, the icon duplicates. This is not ideal, as I would like to see only one icon in the location where I pinned it, and be able to use the Win+Num keyboard shortcut. Is there a solution to this problem? I have searched the forums but have not found anything helpful.

[image: duplicates screenshot]